# Validate person without value in date column

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table with several employees. They have the following columns empid,datecolumn1,is_valid.

Very few employees have a more than one record in the table. If an employee has more than one record in the table I would like to 'invalidate' one of the records on the following condition:
1. If a employee has more than one record in the table then the record with no value in the datecolumn1 is valid (update is_valid to 1) and the record with value in datecolumn1 is not valid (update is_valid to 0).

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ben points out, you've stated that if `datecolumn1` is NULL you want the `is_valid` column to be set to both 0 and 1.  Assuming you fix that, you may need to adjust this `CASE` statement depending on which way you decide is correct.

```
UPDATE employees 
   SET is_valid = (CASE WHEN datecolumn1 IS NULL
                        THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                    END)
 WHERE empid IN (SELECT e.empid
                   FROM employees e
                  GROUP BY emempid
                 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Ah.  I'd not known about the HAVING tag.  Cool.

Answer (score 1):

create a staging table, and fill it by a SELECT on the original table with a GROUP BY employee Id (or whatever your unique identifier is).  Create a second staging table and fill it by SELECTING on the original table and excluding all rows that match rows in your grouped table.  Now you have a table that contains only those people with multiple rows.  From your original table, set is_valid to 0 on all rows that match employee id with the second staging table and also have no datecolumn1 (or perhaps that also have a datecolumn1 - your question as of this writing is a bit unclear.) and is_valid to 1 on the others.  Once done with that, delete the staging tables, and you should have what you need.

You could also do this with a single more complicated multiselect call, but I find it helpful to use staging tables when things get complicated.